# Root Partition not found after Dell Configuration Tool

Tags: boot, partition, manjaro

So, I have a dell xps running Manjaro, and recently the computer decided it needed to run some sort of dell configuration tool upon booting (I recently replaced the battery, so perhaps this is what triggered this?). After it did this, I get the following when trying to boot into Manjaro

```
mount: /new_root: can't find UUID=7be69e31_etc_etc. 
You are now being dropped into an emergency shell. 
sh: can't access tty: job control turned off. 
[rootfs ]#
```

Best I can tell is my hard drive cant be found. In fact, if i boot from a live CD, my main hard drive (where the linux root filesystem is installed) doesn't show up in the partition manager. Running "fdisk -l /dev/sda" gives

```
Disk /dev/sda: 14.91 GiB, 16008609792 bytes, 31266816 sectors
Disk model: Cruzer Glide    
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x12d14d7d

Device     Boot   Start     End Sectors Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *         64 6219251 6219188   3G  0 Empty
/dev/sda2       6219252 6227443    8192   4M ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)
```

However, if I go into the grub shell and run ls, I get

```
(hd0), (hd0, gpt2), (hd0, gpt1)
```

It seems that gpt2 is my main 250gig SSD. And "ls (hd0, gpt2)" confirms that the UUID of this partition is "7be69e31_etc_etc". So it seems grub can find the hard drive still... But I have no idea how to get my system to boot again. Im really out of my depth here, so any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is just showing your USB flash drive Cruser Glide. Did the Dell update run a UEFI update? Dell was updating many older UEFI due to an issue. But UEFI updates often reset many settings to defaults. Or is drive now RAID or Intel RST not AHCI which you probably changed when you first installed. And maybe other settings also?

Comment: That was it! The configuration tool must have switched the drive to RAID. Once I switched it back to AHCI, it booted up normally again. Thanks so much. If you post this as a reply I will accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Report is just showing your USB flash drive - Cruiser Glide.

Did the Dell update run a UEFI update?
Dell was updating many older UEFI due to an issue.

But UEFI updates often reset many settings to defaults.
Or is drive now RAID or Intel RST not AHCI which you probably changed when you first installed.

And maybe other UEFI settings also?